# python thread without calling target

Tags: python, python-3.x

can some one please tell me how can I create thread without calling target.
below program takes 15 seconds and I`enter code here` need to make it to 5 sec

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
listofval=[5,4,3,2,1]
userstart = time.perf_counter()
for value in listofval:    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as executor:
        executor.map(value)        
        time.sleep(value)
        print(value)
userend = time.perf_counter()
print(f'user table finished in {userstart-userend} seconds thread')
```

Comment: What exactly is the thread supposed to do? You merely pass it a number ; it's sheer luck that this even works.

Comment: Hi, MisterMiyagi I need to run this with multiple threads it is actually taking 15 sec. i need to run this in 5 seconds without adding another function for this

Comment: What do you mean by "without adding another function"? If you want the thread to both sleep *and* print, you need a new function – there is no builtin that does both.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def func(value):
    time.sleep(value)
    print(value)

listofval=[5,4,3,2,1]
userstart = time.perf_counter()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as executor:
    executor.map(func, listofval)
userend = time.perf_counter()
print(f'user table finished in {userstart-userend} seconds thread')
```

As is written in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) you need to pass a function to be called and list of params for every function.

> `map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)`
>
> - the iterables are collected immediately rather than lazily;
> - func is executed asynchronously and several calls to func may be made concurrently.

---

Edit: my output

```
1
2
3
4
5
user table finished in -5.005814707999889 seconds thread
```

Comment: yes agreed with func, but i dont want to add another function, because in my code I need to run in the same function. is it possible ?

Comment: No, it is not possible to define what a separated thread is supposed to run without giving it a callable. You can pass `time.sleep` directly to the `executor` like this: `executor.map(time.sleep, listofval)`. Note that this won't allow you to print anything from other threads but the result will be something like `user table finished in -5.0056886410002335 seconds thread`.

Can you share why you don't want to define a separated function?